# Adding and deleteing from saved addresses. How would a user know that swiping means delete?

Tags: usability, gui-design, swipe

I’m building an app for smartphones. A feature in the app requires users to enter an address. Normally, the user would touch the text input field and type it in using the system keyboard, but the user can also double tap the input field which brings up a list of saved addresses. The problems are 1) how to add to saved addresses 2) how to remove from saved addresses
Possible solutions:

1)  After the user manually types in the address the first time, an icon can appear beside it to save it to the address book
2)  This is where I’m stuck. There could be a small x on the right side of the button with each address. But the user may accidentally delete it when trying to use the address. I also though of using swiping to delete an entry. My question is, **how does a user know an item is swipabl**e and that it means to delete it?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxufnF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

We already have the list with the saved addresses, but it looks a little different from what I could show with the mockup (for example the list items look more like buttons so the user would know they're clickable).

Answer (score 1):

I think the way [gmail handles swiping to delete](http://ccm.net/faq/44976-how-to-set-swipe-gestures-in-the-gmail-app) is perfect:

[image]

Three pieces of this interaction are key:

**1. There's a clear indication that the user's swiping action means deleting.**
This is shown with the trash icon **during** the swiping motion.

**2. There's clear feedback *after* the swipe that something was deleted.** The deleted item is clearly marked with a "Deleted" label and is brightly colored to show the contrast with the remaining items.

**3. There's a very useful "Undo" button available after the swipe.** This gives users reassurance that any unintentional actions are not permanent. Perfect for first-time users of the app or the expected use case of accidental swipes.

With time, users will likely understand that swiping an address means deleting it in your app. I think providing the ability to undo it when necessary will help with the adoption of the "swipe-to-delete" action.